# Regular Expression accidentally changing variable value?

Tags: php, regex

Here's the scoop.  I'm using regular expressions to find images and insert "../../" at the beginning of their sources.  Not only is it not working, though, but the variable holding the name (including extension) of the image file is changing when I run the RegEx. If I comment out the 'preg_replace' line, the variable echos out properly.  Can anyone tell me what's wrong?  Thanks in advance!

```
$imagefile = substr($filedata,($jpgbeginning+1),(($jpg+3)-$jpgbeginning));
$filedata = preg_replace('/(<img\s+.*?src=")(.*\\.(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif).*?>)/', '<img src="../'.$imagefile.'" />', $filedata);
echo $imagefile."<br /><br />";
```

Additionally, in the regular expression it is doubling the "../" part, so that is actually outputting as ../../ for some reason.  Thanks again!

Comment: You seem to have majorly confused `$filedata` and `$imagefile` with eachother, as you're using them forwards and backwards all the time (for example, in your example, `$imagefile` doesn't get any regex attached to it, but rather just the `substr`, while `$filedata` replaces the regex on itself).

Comment: you really should NOT be using regexes like this. use DOM to extract the src attribute, giving you the bare url. that'll simplify one level of manipulation.

Comment: Re: h2oo... - $imagefile is simply for the purpose of getting the full name of the image, and $filedata actually should be doing the regex on itself.  I am updating $filedata with the regex.

Comment: Re: Marc - I can't use DOM because the code is not a part of the page it is editing.  $filedata is actually holding the text from an imported html file.

Answer (score 0):

The following preg_replace should work:

```
preg_replace("/(<img\s+src\s*=\s*\")(.+?)(?=\")/","$1../../$2", HTML);
```